# Determining the Current Page without use of request or URL

Tags: url, cache

I'm in a situation whereby our Caching module is obfuscating the requests and the URLs, making it difficult to tell what the current page is.

For example - without caching:

```
/checkout/cart
```

with caching:

```
/899472304723khb4i23grhi29dhokhsabidb3q78bdi2bdiwbyudybasud6s81g
```

This is true regardless of reading the request via `$this->getRequest();`, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` or by reading `Mage::helper('core/helper')->getCurrentUrl();` - the URL in all cases is obfuscated as above.

Due to this, I'm a little stuck on how to detect the current page without this information. Can someone help?

Comment: what exactly is your caching module caching? And why dont you have the Request object, which is a base requirement for nearly every visible part?

Comment: You may want to check if your caching module has any helpers to try to decode that URL.

Comment: @Flyingmana it's a page cache module, and I do have a request object, but as I mentioned in the question, the request URL is always obfuscated. I'll check through the caching module for a decoding system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I utilised my blacklist in the caching module to remove the cache control of those pages. They aren't pages that are required to be cached anyway (cart/checkout/etc.) as they are specific to each user.

This solved this issue, albeit in a roundabout kind of way. I could then read the request.